# powershell parsing of a geojson API request for Mapbox

Tags: powershell, curl, mapbox, geojson

I have been using an inline Windows 10 Powershell command to successfully download static Google and Mapbox png images but cannot get Powershell to successfully pass a geojson object to utilise the overlay feature in Mapbox. I am not an expert Powershell user and I expect that I need to add further syntax to get this to work?

The following code, taken from the Mapbox online examples for curl, works OK:

```
powershell -command "(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).Proxy.Credentials=[System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials";" 
    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v10/static/-73.99,40.70,12/500x300?access_token=<access-token-removed-here>' 
    -outfile test_no_overlay.png"
```

but the following Mapbox curl example using geojson hash table formatting to include an overlay marker (which will work via a browser) does not work via Powershell:

```
powershell -command "(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).Proxy.Credentials=[System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials";" 
    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v10/static/geojson(%7B%22type%22%3A%22Point%22%2C%22coordinates%22%3A%5B-73.99%2C40.7%5D%7D)/-73.99,40.70,12/500x300?access_token=<access-token-removed-here>' 
    -outfile test_overlay.png"
```

The reported error is:

> Invoke-RestMethod : {"message":"Failed parsing geojson"} At line:1
>   char:110
>   + ... redentials; Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/ ...
>   +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod],
>   WebException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand

This non-proxy version also works from the Powershell prompt:

```
$response=Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v10/static/geojson(%7B%22type%22%3A%22Point%22%2C%22coordinates%22%3A%5B-73.99%2C40.7%5D%7D)/-73.99,40.70,12/500x300?access_token=<access-token-removed-here>'
    -outfile test_overlay.png
```

so it appears that there is a syntax issue that I need to overcome to make it perform in a single-line CMD format?

Comment: Do you run the commands in cmd.exe or poweshell? With line breaks and not escaped inner double quotes they should error out in either environment.

Comment: The examples were run in a CMD window but in operational mode I send the powershell string directly to Windows. The non-overlay version delivers the requested PNG OK with no errors.